# Why do Linux instructions almost never include sudo even when it is obviously necessary?

Tags: permissions, sudo

Why do Linux instructions almost never include sudo even when it is obviously necessary?

You see it a lot, for example, you will see something like:

"Edit /etc/hosts by doing $nano /etc/hosts and type in this huge block of text"

Then you find out you don't have permissions and all that work was for nothing (unless you can copy paste/xclip it all or something).

Then you do what should have been written and go "sudo nano /etc/hosts" and try again.

The example here is just that: an example. This happens a lot and can be really confusing sometimes. Specially when the system allows for a command to be run as user and as root/sudo and you really need the second.

Comment: Ask the person who wrote the instructions.

Comment: It's a general thing. Almost like a fashion thing that everyone does. I do believe it has a side intent to protect the end user, but can't see another reason for it. Also, understand the question before commenting.

Comment: I don't see it often.

Comment: Often, the prompt is shown. If the prompt ends in $, then use `sudo`. If it's #, don't.

Comment: When writing a long set of commands or detailed instructions it is frustrating to keep writing sudo foo sudo bar etc. Generally people will make note to run commands as root and generally if you are modifying files outside of $HOME you will need to do so as root.

Comment: Not only editing files. Sometimes even just running binaries and services/daemons commands, you will get an a-ok sign when in fact it was really necessary to do the same thing but as sudo/root for it to all work. And in those cases it can be really confusing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Why do Linux instructions almost never include sudo even when it is obviously necessary?

- Because not all Linux systems use `sudo`.
- Because the guide you are following is not targeted towards "debian" style systems.

> Then do what you should do: sudo nano /etc/hosts and try again.

Nope. You do `sudo !!` and press enter. The system will repeat the last command and put `sudo` in front of it.

Comment: What I'd do is save elsewhere and copy over.

Comment: Yeh, that's the logic that I had envisioned. Still seems bad design to have instruction where you need to run as root without at least a sign saying so.